# Flutter make a simple Ticket widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter i want to clip optional part of `Container` to make this widget:

[image]

clipping the widget to have two semicircle on top and bottom of that.

for some feature of this clipped widget i want to have some optional feature, for example:

[image]

clipping top, bottom of that optional and space from right. how can i clipping `Container` with optional feature?

Comment: @Kherel could you help me on this question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use custom clipper + arcToPoint path method to create clean arcs.

Like that:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as v_math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
      ClipPath(
        clipper: DolDurmaClipper(right: 40, holeRadius: 20),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          width: 300,
          height: 95,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Text('first example'),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      ClipPath(
        clipper: DolDurmaClipper(right: 100, holeRadius: 40),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          width: 200,
          height: 250,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
          child: Text('second example'),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class DolDurmaClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  DolDurmaClipper({@required this.right, @required this.holeRadius});

  final double right;
  final double holeRadius;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right - holeRadius, 0.0)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - right, 0),
        clockwise: false,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - right - holeRadius, size.height),
        clockwise: false,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      );

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(DolDurmaClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: now they ar on the up and on the bottom of widget,how to make them on the side of widget?

Comment: how to make them on left and right side of widget? @Kherel

Comment: how to give border color, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

To create same shape for left and right side of container you can use this.

```
class DolDurmaClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double holeRadius;
  final double bottom;

  DolDurmaClipper({required this.holeRadius, required this.bottom});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height - bottom - holeRadius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(0, size.height - bottom),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - bottom)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width, size.height - bottom - holeRadius),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      );

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(DolDurmaClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: Hey Khayti, do you know how I could add multiple semi-circles on each side with that code you shared? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Powermaster, I shared code in new answer, Please check. I hope it useful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple semi-circles on each side all we need to do is add lineTo and arcPoint as many circle you need.

So updated getClip function will be as shown below

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
//For left side shape of container
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height - 100 - holeRadius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(0, size.height - 100),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height - 50 - holeRadius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(0, size.height - 50),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
//For Right side shape of container
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - 100)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width, size.height - 100 - holeRadius),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - 50)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width, size.height - 50 - holeRadius),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      );

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```