# Clip Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, clip

> I want to clip a container in such a way like below image

[image]

I have read about a couple of clip but don't know how to achieve this.

I have tried implementing clipping using..

```
Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ClipRRect(
        child: Stack(
          ///clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 250,
                  height: 250,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I have found a way to do this [using CustomClipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860813/flutter-make-a-simple-ticket-widget)

Comment: can you include what you've tried so far

Comment: Ok @YeasinSheikh . I will add it

Comment: @TaimoorKhan you want design lilke this

Comment: @MobinAnsar I need to draw using clip or something like that I don't want to use image as background

Comment: try to use ShapeBorder or ClipPath